# Get the Header and Item format in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have requirement for arranging header and item data in a certain format.

The format I have :

```
Country State
---------------
India   Delhi
India   Gujarat
India   Kerela
US      Texas
US      NJ
```

Country and State are fields names

I require this in the following format

```
Country State
---------------
India   
      Delhi
      Gujarat
      Kerela
US  
      Texas
      NJ
```

Here the concept is that if the headers are the same then they should not be repeated while the Items for that header should be coming below without the header data being repeated.

can anyone suggest me the solution to attain this format.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you've written so far.

Comment: which database you are using?

Comment: didnt write any code as of now...and I'm using SQL Server

Comment: Please tag with the actual RDBMS (product and version) and please read [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056)  and [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: On the first sight this looks like a *business rule issue* for your presentation layer. Not really something a database is meant to do...

Comment: it is a business rule...I have to make a load file in this format based  on the report I had extracted

Comment: Then use a *reporting* tool. SQL is a querying language, not a report designer. SQL Server's own Reporting Services makes it trivial to generate stepped tables like that

Answer (score 0):

For me, the question is very unclear but you should check which i have done for the above with the help of `lag()` function

```
select (case when lag(A) over (order by A) is null then A else '' end) A,
       (case when lag(B) over (order by B) is null then B else '' end) B,
       (case when lag(C) over (order by C) is null then C else D end) C,
       (case when lag(C) over (order by C) is null then D else E end) D,
       (case when lag(C) over (order by C) is null then E else F end) E,
       (case when lag(C) over (order by C) is null then F else '' end) F
from table t
```

**EDIT :** First, as other suggests you could do that in application layer easily, but still you could do that with `SQL`(Not recommended)

Use `row_number()` function to assing ranking to the country

```
select 
        case when (row_number() over (partition by Country order by State)) > 1 
             then '' else c.Country 
        end Country,
        t.State
from table t
```

Comment: @NaveenMadaparthi could u edit the `q` with some more sample data.

Comment: @NaveenMadaparthi this is not right place to write here for above go with your question section and edit.

Comment: changed the requirement into a simpler format..can you help me out on this